# It's possible to observe LiveData from dialog view?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

Dialog created from activity or fragment with custom view, and I need to observe liveData on dialog custom view. I don't think it's OK to use `viewLifecycleOwner` from Fragment, but there is no `LifecycleOwner` with `Dialog`.

Comment: If you find any answer, please edit your post, Thank. I am in need too.

Comment: @Francky380 RxJava is much powerful and controllable to me, I use RxJava in this case now. Just subscribe the `Connectable`, and dispose the disposable container on dismiss.

Comment: Okay. Finally I just passed my variable in the constructor of the dialog. When the Dialog is open, no one can modify the LiveData, so its value remains the same. Do you think it`s a good practice?